# How to avoid inserting duplicate entries into an azure storage table while using Push-OutputBinding?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have an Azure function that is updating an Azure Storage Table. The function does this:

```
$returnArray = @()
foreach ($record in $recordsFromApi) {
    $tableData = [PsCustomObject]@ {
        partitionKey = $record.partitionKey
        rowKey = $record.userId
        data = $record.userData
    }
    $returnArray += $tableData
}
Push-OutputBinding -Name dataTable -Value $returnArray -Clobber
```

This function gets data from an API which is put into an array. That array is written to the Azure Storage Table. The problem I'm having, is that if they `partitionKey` in the table already exists (duplicate data) the rest of the entries do not get inserted into the table. I get the error message `The specified entity already exists.`.

I've tried using parameters like `-Force` and `-Upsert Replace` but I don't think those are supported anymore.

How can I handle the duplicate records from the api in a way that I can still insert the non-duplicated records?

Comment: if I understand correctly, you can use a `HashSet<T>` and add those `$partitionKey` values to it, then check with a condition if the `$partitionKey` is already added, then return early (dont add to the array)

Comment: where does $partitionKey come from? and why the loop, looks like you create for each entry in $recordsFromApi the same object with the same values

Comment: "I've tried using parameters like `-Force` and `-Upsert Replace`" - is there some code missing from your question?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I need to check if `$partitionKey` is in the Azure Storage Table.

Comment: @Toni `$partitionKey` comes from an API. The API returns multiple records so I loop through each record it returns to get the data for that record. Then, I upload the records to a stroage table.

Comment: can you query the storage table to collect all "partitionKeys" before running the code you have? if so, my comment still applies, you can add them all to the `HashSet`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen those are parameters I added to the end `Push-OutputBinding` like `Push-OutputBinding -Name dataTable -Value $returnArray -Force` but that doesn't work (it's not supported anymore)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon the table has over a hundred thousands records. I was hoping there would be a way to deal with this on the PowerShell side.

Comment: not really... you loop: ```foreach ($record in $recordsFromApi)``` so the single element is stored in ```$record``` but once you build the object you do not e.g. ```partitionKey = $record.partitionKey``` you simply do  ```partitionKey =$partitionkey```, so in the end all objects stored in ```$returnArray``` are probably identical

Comment: @Toni you're right, I missed that. I updated the question. My problem still stands.

Comment: now it looks better :-)

Comment: you can simply do before looping: ```$recordsFromApi  = $recordsFromApi | sort-object -property partitionKey -unique```

Comment: Well yes, you could handle this from PowerShell side without querying the table, i.e.: `try` => insert value => if error handle that record, either exclude it or use a different `partitionKey`. but that would require a `Push-OutputBinding` per record to add, not sure if that's possible and / or how efficient that is

Comment: @Toni this will check the storage table?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon `Push-OutputBinding` only supports one insert per function execution.

Comment: then I dont see other option than querying the existing values on the table.